# Is there is any way to write this Rails order query with Ruby symbols instead of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-order-by

I need to join one table with another prior to ordering records. So far, I've found I can only do the ordering using a string, like so:

```
customer.joins(:product).order("products.position")
```

I don't like using hard-coded string values, it feels unsafe. It would be nice if I could use Ruby symbols instead, like below:

```
customer.joins(:product).order(:products => :position) #doesn't work
```

How can I do it?

I have a feeling it should be possible, since you can use Ruby symbols when joining a table and doing a `where`, as demonstrated in the example below:

```
customer.joins(:product).where(:products => {:manufacturer_id => @manufacturer.id})
```

Comment: I agree, this seems like something that could be implemented.

`customer.includes(:products).where(products: {manufacturer_id: @manufacturer.id}).references(:products).order(products: {created_at: :desc})`

This query seems like it would solve the problem raised in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

No, activerecord was not designed this way.  The best reason I can think of is because how would you specify `ASC` or `DESC` with that type of naming?  You must specify the full statement in a string format for it to work.